# If startTime is lesser than currenttime how to calculate proper time in this case?

Tags: javascript

I have got restaurants business **startTime** and **endTime** for the **todays** date .

I have a requirement as such when clicked on **Order now** button depending on the Restaurants `startTime` and `endTime` i need to display a alert meesage 
saying services will resume with in next **XX** Minutes

This is my code

```
var startTime = '04:00 PM';

var endTime  = '5:30 PM';


var now  = new Date();
var startDate = dateObj(startTime);
var endDate  = dateObj(endTime);

 var openorclosed = now < endDate && now > startDate ? 'open' : 'closed';

if(openorclosed=='open')
{
   alert('Restaurant is Open');
    // do nothing
}

else if(openorclosed=='closed')
{
    var diffinMinutes = getMinutesBetweenDates(startDate,now);
    var minutes = Math.floor(diffinMinutes);
    alert('service not available for the next '+minutes+' min');
}


function dateObj(d) {
    var parts = d.split(/:|\s/),
    date = new Date();
    if (parts.pop().toLowerCase() == 'pm') parts[0] = (+parts[0]) + 12;
    date.setHours(+parts.shift());
    date.setMinutes(+parts.shift());
    return date;
}

function getMinutesBetweenDates(startDate, now) {
    var diff = startDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
    return (diff / 60000);
}
```

**If the startTime is bigger than the Current time then its working perfectly (Displaying correclty)**

However if the startTime is lesser than the Current time then its displaying values in negative values

Could anybody please let me know how to display correclty within minutes incase startTime is lesser ??

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wajzvqqx/1/

Thank you very much .

Comment: Are you sure you don't know how to compare values to know which one is the biggest?

Comment: How do you know which timezone the restaurant is in? Or the user?

Answer (score 1):

User this code when the shop is `closed`:

```
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+1);
```

You were calculating start and end date objects from current date.

So if shop is closed for the day, add one more day to the start date.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wajzvqqx/4/)**

Comment: You could also use a modulo when calculating your difference to ignore this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

If your value is negative, add a whole day:

```
var diffinMinutes = getMinutesBetweenDates(startDate,now);
if (diffinMinutes < 0) diffinMinutes = diffinMinutes + 1440;
var minutes = Math.floor(diffinMinutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the `getMinutesBetweenDate` function to get the difference like this:

```
function getMinutesBetweenDates(startDate, now) {
    var diff;
    if (startDate > now) {
        diff = startDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
    } else {
        diff = now.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    }
    return (diff / 60000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you , but Assume that the startTime is 04:00 PM and  endTime  = '5:30 PM'; then the alert i am getting is 107 , which is wrong know .

Comment: Ah sorry misunderstood question, the problem is when the current time is after the `endTime`